# The Application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

i running my program but the pop up windows showing that application was unable to start correctly. and i check in output there are many message like this:

```
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'E:\TA\Baru\FIX\oculus+ovr\ovrvisionsdk_windows_19022014\ovrvisionsdk_windows\example_vs2008\x64\Debug\example_wizapply.exe', Symbols loaded.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ovrvision64d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'example_wizapply.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x1c50) has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0xa74) has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x19b4) has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The program '[9124] example_wizapply.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Comment: BTW, ***Cannot find or open the PDB file*** will most likely not help you debug this issue. This just means you don't have the debugging symbols installed for some microsoft dlls. You generally don't need that unless you need to debug the functionality of the dlls. The program must be successfully loaded to make real use of this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with loading libraries. Check the availability of libraries and links to them.